# Computer becomes unresponsive during sleep

Tags: windows-7, freeze, sleep

I have a strange issue with my personal computer. My computer becomes completely unresponsive if it sits idle long enough to trigger sleep mode. It shuts off output to my monitors and while the LEDs on my keyboard and mouse are lit, they will not wake the computer. Now for the weird part, I have sleep and hibernate completely disabled in Windows power options, as well as in my BIOS. I am searched high and low, and had found similar questions here but none offered solutions to my problem, so I wanted to list out my hardware to see if someone can identify a known issue or something.

I can prevent this unresponsive state if I lock my computer when I leave it. It does not appear to be a temp issue because both CPU and GPU idle in known safe temperatures. This started about a month ago, but there has been no hardware changes prior to it starting.

Build:
CPU:i5-2500k
MOBO:ASUS P8H77-V LE
RAM: G.Skill Sniper 2133 8gigs (2x4gig)
GPU: Sapphire 7870 XT (Tahiti Chipset)
SSD: Samsung 840 250gig
Storage Drive: 2TB 7200 RPM Drive by Seagate (I think, not at the computer now). 
Monitors: 2x 24inch Dell LED

Comment: Is your question how to wake your computer, or how to prevent it from sleeping?  If the latter, you might check the various power saving options for the monitor, drives, etc (Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options, click Change plan settings, click Change advanced power settings, and work through the options)

Comment: I apologize if the question is unclear, it is how to either get it to wake from this sleep state, or prevent it completely. Because as of now it is still sleeping even though all the options in Power Options are set to Never Sleep or Hibernate. BIOS is also set to prevent sleeping.

Comment: I suggested checking the power settings for the monitor, hard drive, etc, as even if you have sleep disabled, individual components may be going into various power save states, that could be causing the system to appear to be powered down.

Answer (score 1):

To get your mouse and keyboard to wake your computer from sleep, Open Device Manager and for the mouse and keyboard, open up the dropdown list and then right click and go to properties on the entry. You should get a Device Properties window with 4 tabs, the last tab being Power Management. On that tab there should be a checkbox for 'Allow this device to wake the computer'. Turn that flag on and see if you have any luck.

I never use hibernate (have it disabled), but I'm pretty sure you cannot 'wake' you computer from hibernate without pressing the power button.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have to give you a +1 just for reminding me of this setting.  Having a similar problem as the author which is odd because its an extact duplicate image of a system state that didn't have a single problem.

Comment: I never use hibernate either, I just stated it because at this point I am unsure of the state my computer goes into, whether it is hibernate or sleep because nothing wakes it. I can only get use back by completely shutting down (holding down the power button for several seconds), and when I do that it obviously crashes any programs I have running. But I will try your suggestion in device properties to see if anything is off there.

Comment: Tried this last night, all the "allow to wake" options are checked on all my devices. I am beginning to think there is an issue somewhere possibly with my motherboard. I think I might just have to live with the issue.